# Sending NSMutableDictionary between view controllers--not working on iPhone 3GS

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview, nsmutabledictionary

I have an app in which I have several views in a UITabBar.  The first view creates data and sends it to a table view where it is added to an array and displayed.

It has been working fine for me (on my iPhone 4). However I recently discovered that it does not work on iPhone 3GS.  Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: So - let us see the code then :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the array empty when used in 3gs by any chance?